Pressing z twice does not trigger transform across normal axis
When I press g to move, then press z to move among global z axis, then z again, blender does not trigger moving among the normal axis as expected. It remains stuck to the global z axis, and pressing z again returns to free movement.
This also occurs for the y and x axis.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

When your Transform Orientation is set to Global (which it presumably is if pressing Z once locks to global axis), then pressing Z twice will lock transformations to the local axis, not normal. Local means aligned to the object's orientation in Object Mode.

...which means, if the object is not rotated, global and local axis will be the same is this wasn't clear from my first comment. @Jakemoyo Why share the file?

You need to change the reference system to normal (usually it's "global" and it's at the top of the 3d view)

@Gordon Brinkmann is there a way to set it to be the normal axis instead?

Yes, set the Transform Orientation in the dropdown menu to Normal, then press Z once. Pressing it twice will then be global.

@DanielMöller A reference system or frame of reference is the coordinate system which the object's location, rotation and scale are relative to. What you mean is the Transform Orientation, which can be set to be different/independent from the frame of reference.
